# Heroku Memcache issue - Dalli::NetworkError: localhost:11211 is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached, thin, dalli

I have recently upgraded Rails to 3.2.2 and now I seem to be running into Memcache related issues... can anyone help?

My production config:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
 :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
 :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
 :allow_reload => false
}
```

Dalli gem is in the bundle

```
gem 'dalli'
```

I've added the memcache addon via herokus GUI.

My Procfile is thusly (also have the 'thin' gem installed):

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT thin -e $RACK_ENV
```

but I'm getting these errors even when I try to do simple cache maintenance in the console:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211')
=> #<Dalli::Client:0x00000007501980 @servers="localhost:11211", @options={}, @ring=nil>
irb(main):002:0> dc.flush_all
localhost:11211 failed (count: 0)
Dalli::NetworkError: localhost:11211 is down:  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/server.rb:47:in `request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/options.rb:18:in `block in request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/options.rb:17:in `request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/client.rb:158:in `block in flush'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/client.rb:158:in `map'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.2.1/lib/dalli/client.rb:158:in `flush'
    from (irb):2
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

And of course, asset serving is also failing:

```
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: cache error: No server available
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
2012-09-29T02:26:29+00:00 app[web.3]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
```

Is this a problem with my config ? Is this a Heroku issue?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this as it is set to those things by default...

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
 :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
 :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
 :allow_reload => false
}
```

...once you make sure your version of dalli has this [commit](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/commit/0625e361aafdd2efb397fab6b22a2a95a707be38) which is in the latest version.